# removing background from PNG image in mono game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame, game-development

I am a new monogame user. I am trying to get rid of the white background in tennis ball that moves in this pong project I am working on:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf322.png)

I want to keep the tennis ball itself but only the tennis ball. I don't want the square frame the ball is in. here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Ping_Pong
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>  
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    //instance variables for font
    private SpriteFont font;                   
    private int score = 0;                      


    // the score
    int m_Score1 = 0;
    int m_Score2 = 0;
    //Texture2D m_textureNumbers;                     

    Rectangle[] m_ScoreRect = null;

    // the ball
    Ball m_ball;
    Texture2D m_textureBall;

    // the paddles
    Paddle m_paddle1;
    Paddle m_paddle2;
    Texture2D m_texturePaddle;

    // constants
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // use a fixed frame rate of 30 frames per second
        IsFixedTimeStep = true;
        TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 33);

        InitScreen();
        InitGameObjects();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    // screen-related init tasks
    public void InitScreen()
    {
        // back buffer
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }

    // game-related init tasks
    public void InitGameObjects()
    {
        // create an instance of our ball
        m_ball = new Ball();

        // set the size of the ball
        m_ball.Width = 15.0f;                     
        m_ball.Height = 15.0f;                    

        // create 2 instances of our paddle
        m_paddle1 = new Paddle();
        m_paddle2 = new Paddle();

        // set the size of the paddles
        m_paddle1.Width = 15.0f;
        m_paddle1.Height = 100.0f;
        m_paddle2.Width = 15.0f;
        m_paddle2.Height = 100.0f;

        // map the digits in the image to actual numbers
        m_ScoreRect = new Rectangle[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            m_ScoreRect[i] = new Rectangle(                                                         //none of this will be used for sprite font
                i * 45, // X
                0,      // Y
                45,     // Width
                75);    // Height
        }

        ResetGame();
    }

    // initial play state, called when the game is first
    // run, and whever a player scores 10 goals
    public void ResetGame()
    {
        // reset scores
        m_Score1 = 0;
        m_Score2 = 0;

        // place the ball at the center of the screen
        m_ball.X =
            SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - m_ball.Width / 2;
        m_ball.Y =
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - m_ball.Height / 2;

        // set a speed and direction for the ball
        m_ball.DX = 5.0f;
        m_ball.DY = 4.0f;

        // place the paddles at either end of the screen
        m_paddle1.X = 30;
        m_paddle1.Y =
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - m_paddle1.Height / 2;
        m_paddle2.X =
            SCREEN_WIDTH - 30 - m_paddle2.Width;
        m_paddle2.Y =
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - m_paddle1.Height / 2;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

       font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"media\Ariel"); // Use the name of your sprite font file here instead of 'Score'.            
        LoadGameGraphics();
    }

    // load our textures from disk
    protected void LoadGameGraphics()
    {
        // load the texture for the ball
        m_textureBall =
            Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"media\pong_ball");
        m_ball.Visual = m_textureBall;

        // load the texture for the paddles
        m_texturePaddle =
            Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"media\paddle");
        m_paddle1.Visual = m_texturePaddle;
        m_paddle2.Visual = m_texturePaddle;

         // load the texture for the score
         // m_textureNumbers =
          //Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"media\numbers");           
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // update the ball's location on the screen
        MoveBall();
        // update the paddles' locations on the screen
        MovePaddles();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    // move the ball based on it's current DX and DY 
    // settings. check for collisions
    private void MoveBall()
    {
        // actually move the ball
        m_ball.X += m_ball.DX;
        m_ball.Y += m_ball.DY;

        // did ball touch top or bottom side?
        if (m_ball.Y <= 0 ||
            m_ball.Y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - m_ball.Height)
        {
            // reverse vertical direction
            m_ball.DY *= -1;
        }

        // did ball touch the left side?
        if (m_ball.X <= 0)
        {
            // at higher speeds, the ball can leave the 
            // playing field, make sure that doesn't happen
            m_ball.X = 0;

            // increment player 2's score
            m_Score2++;

            // reduce speed, reverse direction
            m_ball.DX = 5.0f;
        }

        // did ball touch the right side?
        if (m_ball.X >= SCREEN_WIDTH - m_ball.Width)
        {
            // at higher speeds, the ball can leave the 
            // playing field, make sure that doesn't happen
            m_ball.X = SCREEN_WIDTH - m_ball.Width;

            // increment player 1's score
            m_Score1++;

            // reduce speed, reverse direction
            m_ball.DX = -5.0f;
        }

        // reset game if a player scores 10 goals
        if (m_Score1 > 99 || m_Score2 > 99)
        {
            ResetGame();
        }

        // did ball hit the paddle from the front?
        if (CollisionOccurred())
        {
            // reverse hoizontal direction
            m_ball.DX *= -1;

            // increase the speed a little.
            m_ball.DX *= 1.15f;
        }
    }

    // check for a collision between the ball and paddles
    private bool CollisionOccurred()
    {
        // assume no collision
        bool retval = false;

        // heading towards player one
        if (m_ball.DX < 0)
        {
            Rectangle b = m_ball.Rect;
            Rectangle p = m_paddle1.Rect;
            retval =
                b.Left < p.Right &&
                b.Right > p.Left &&
                b.Top < p.Bottom &&
                b.Bottom > p.Top;
        }
        // heading towards player two
        else // m_ball.DX > 0
        {
            Rectangle b = m_ball.Rect;
            Rectangle p = m_paddle2.Rect;
            retval =
                b.Left < p.Right &&
                b.Right > p.Left &&
                b.Top < p.Bottom &&
                b.Bottom > p.Top;
        }

        return retval;
    }

    // how much to move paddle each frame
    private const float PADDLE_STRIDE = 10.0f;

    // actually move the paddles
    private void MovePaddles()
    {
        // define bounds for the paddles
        float MIN_Y = 0.0f;
        float MAX_Y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - m_paddle1.Height;

        // get player input
        GamePadState pad1 =
            GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
        GamePadState pad2 =
            GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two);
        KeyboardState keyb =
            Keyboard.GetState();

        // check the controller, PLAYER ONE
        bool PlayerUp =
            pad1.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed;
        bool PlayerDown =
            pad1.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed;

        // also check the keyboard, PLAYER ONE
        PlayerUp |= keyb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W);
        PlayerDown |= keyb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S);

        // move the paddle
        if (PlayerUp)
        {
            m_paddle1.Y -= PADDLE_STRIDE;
            if (m_paddle1.Y < MIN_Y)
            {
                m_paddle1.Y = MIN_Y;
            }
        }
        else if (PlayerDown)
        {
            m_paddle1.Y += PADDLE_STRIDE;
            if (m_paddle1.Y > MAX_Y)
            {
                m_paddle1.Y = MAX_Y;
            }
        }

        // check the controller, PLAYER TWO
        PlayerUp =
            pad2.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed;
        PlayerDown =
            pad2.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed;

        // also check the keyboard, PLAYER TWO
        PlayerUp |= keyb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up);
        PlayerDown |= keyb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down);

        // move the paddle
        if (PlayerUp)
        {
            m_paddle2.Y -= PADDLE_STRIDE;
            if (m_paddle2.Y < MIN_Y)
            {
                m_paddle2.Y = MIN_Y;
            }
        }
        else if (PlayerDown)
        {
            m_paddle2.Y += PADDLE_STRIDE;
            if (m_paddle2.Y > MAX_Y)
            {
                m_paddle2.Y = MAX_Y;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // our game-specific drawing logic
        Render();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
    // draw the score at the specified location
    public void DrawScore(float x, float y, int score)
    {
        //spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)m_textureNumbers,
            //new Vector2(x, y),
           // m_ScoreRect[score % 10],        
            //Color.Gray);
    }

    // actually draw our game objects
    public void Render()
    {
        // black background
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // start rendering our game graphics
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

        // draw the score first, so the ball can
        // move over it without being obscured
        DrawScore((float)SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.25f,
            20, m_Score1);
        DrawScore((float)SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.65f,
            20, m_Score2);

        // render the game objects
        spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)m_ball.Visual, m_ball.Rect, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)m_paddle1.Visual, m_paddle1.Rect, Color.White);                     //uncomment after checking
        spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)m_paddle2.Visual, m_paddle2.Rect, Color.White);                     //uncomment after checking
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "P1:"+m_Score1, new Vector2(50, 100), Color.White);              //uncomment after checking
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "P2:" + m_Score2, new Vector2(400, 100), Color.White);           //uncomment after checking 

        // we're done drawing
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

}
}
```

I already added my asset (PMG image) to the monogame pipeline tool and loaded it to my code as you can see from running the program.

Comment: Does you PNG have a transparent background? Or a white background? If the later, can you edit it to make it transparent?

Comment: PNG has a white background. How do I edit it to have a transparent background? is it possible to do this using visual studio perhaps by using a built in function?

Comment: Many image processing software packages will let you edit a PNG and replace the white with a transparent background. Many are free. Example, Paint.Net

Comment: i changed it to transparent using https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png it worked. Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by simply editing the image.

Comment: @MattBurland, this question is not dependent on the source of the png file, it is a matter of transparency in images when applied to monogame. Please be aware the the common free image editors do not allow for transparency, (Yes Gimp is the exception).  Closing the post based on a web-based workaround seems flaky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this even though the original poster found a website to do it for him.

Do not attempt with a JPEG (the compression guarantees nonuniform color values)

Make the background of the image is a solid color(Any color will do, the default is 255,0,255 magenta.) Make sure that anti-aliasing is turned off in any editor you are using.

Within the Pipeline tool, add the png.
Select the png file in the top left Project window.
Under Processor Parameters: adjust the ColorKeyColor to match the color selected as transparent. This results in an exact color match transparency mask.

The engine will honor proper transparencies in the original png file. This results in better blending,since, it allows multiple values for the alpha, instead of just on or off.